# See WFS or WMS corresponding full http request in QGIS when a layer was added from any of these services

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs, ogc

I have added both a new [WMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service) and a new [WFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service) server into a [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) project, by specifying a generic `GetCapabilities` URL in the appropriate sections in the browser panel:

[image: QGIS browser panel]

After that, I am able to add some of the available layers from these WMS and WFS servers.

Now, how can I find the full corresponding underlying HTTP request (that was probably build under the hood by QGIS), so that I can copy and paste it in a web browser to get the same map?

Comment: add layer >right click> properties and the information tab.

Comment: I've seen that, it's not really formatted as a ready-to-use HTTP request.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have QGIS 3.14, press F12. Otherwise install the Network logger plugin.

[image]

Comment: Didn't know the F12 trick, that's cool !